# How would I convert a midi file to a bin (audio) file?

Tags: python, assembly, midi, bootloader, bin

So I am trying to convert a midi file to a bin file, so it can be played using motherboard beeps in a bootloader. Or can you directly play midi files in a bootloader?

I tried using this python script, but it puts out completely empty files:
*(Usage: Midi2Bin.py [MidiFile] [OutputFile])*

```
import midi, sys

pattern = midi.read_midifile(sys.argv[1])

def pitchconv(pitch):
    return int(round(1193180.0 / (2**((pitch-69)/12.0)*440), 0))

with open(sys.argv[2], "wb") as out:
    pitches = [pitchconv(event.pitch) for event in pattern[1] if isinstance(event, midi.NoteOnEvent)]

    b = 0
    d = 0
    
    t = 0
    o = -1
    for event in pattern[1]:
        if isinstance(event, midi.NoteOnEvent):
            if event.velocity == 0:
                d += int(round(event.tick/48.0, 0))
                p = pitchconv(event.pitch)
                out.write(chr(p & 0xff) + chr(d << 5 | p >> 8))
                b = 0
            else:
                d = int(round(event.tick/48.0, 0))
```

I have been trying to find a solution for 2 days straight now and I can't find it.

[Midi File](https://mega.nz/file/OWByhbQK#YJJtDw8ryYsU35nSine8Wp2TP5FSjO1y_eDEZSSgxIc)

Comment: Use any midi player that has file output, e.g. timidity. Anyway, you won't get much quality with the pc speaker.

Comment: What format is the bin file supposed to have?  Bin is not a file format I am aware of.

Comment: Please be more specific about the format you are trying to produce, ideally provide a spec.